# When does rails controller knows when to use serve embedded html or js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If I'm calling the `index` action in `UsersController`, when does the Rails controller know when to serve up `index.html.erb` or `index.js.erb`? It seems that setting links with the property `remote: true` will direct me `index.js.erb` instead of `index.html.erb` ?

```
link_to 'user#index',  remote: true (=> index.js.erb)
link_to 'user#index' (=> index.html.erb)
```

Are there more scenarios?

How does rails know the difference between a regular `get` request or a `javascript get` request?

Can someone just clarify rails controller defaults when it comes serving up embedded javascript/html file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This thing are done by rails controller. For example, if you have index controller and you want to respond it with html and js

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html   ## respond to embedded html
    format.js     ## respond to js but it is called if remote data is passed (i.e if remote: true is set)
  end
end
```

If you have pass remote in your index page (index.html.erb)

```
<%= link_to "Show", show_path, remote: true %>
```

Then it will respond to index js (i.e. format.js). You need to create index.js.erb file to define logic for it.

You can see in this [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) too.